# Remotely uninstalling application from iPad

Tags: ios, string, localization

Is it possible to uninstall application from an iPad remotely without user's permission?

The client wants an app for secure sharing company data through iPads and some server (something like Dropbox). The requirement form the client also is to wipe all application data from iPad and possibly uninstall application at all when employee is fired :-)

In my opinion neither the data wiping or remote uninstalling is possible. I am just curious if anyone can came with some solution.

I plan simply offer client to open all encrypted documents only inside an app and only when the app is connected to internet. Each time the document is about to be opened (even if the document is cached) authentication is required. When employee is fired documents can't be read.

Answer (score 3):

You're right in your assumption that remote uninstalling is not possible. And data wiping isn't possible without the user's permission. (The only solution I can think of for this is to send a remote notification with instruction to delete files, but the user would have to open the application from that notification, they could just ignore it).

Authentication does sound like a viable solution. Ask the user to sign in when they open the application (and when the app returns from background) and authenticate the sign in remotely on a server. When the user leaves the company, invalidate their login. Encrypt files stored on the device for extra security.

Comment: From iOS 10+, using a [Notification Service Extension](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/modifying_content_in_newly_delivered_notifications), you may intercept notifications before them being delivered to the user. From iOS 11+, you may use [PushKit](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/fileprovider/content_and_change_tracking/tracking_your_file_provider_s_changes/using_push_notifications_to_signal_changes) to be notified of updates.

Answer (score 2):

You could do something where your app checks with a server, each time it is run, for a "kill flag".  It could still have content on board but it just does not allow access until it has confirmed there is no kill flag.  If there is a kill flag then it wipes all sensitive data.

Another thing to consider is that devices connected through Exchange can be remotely wiped by an administrator.  If your client uses exchange and is ok with the idea of completely wiping the device this could be a procedure they could implement.